# NumberGroupSeparator return strange symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application I am trying to get number group separator for specified locale. For US the code below return `,` number separator as expected but for RU(Russian) it returns `&#160;` instead of space. Is this encoded space in Unicode? How to get normal ASCII symbol?

```
Context.GetPrincipalAppLanguageForRequest().GetCultureInfo().NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator
```

Comment: Just google &#160 and it will immediately give you the answer. That would have been much faster than typing up the question... Google - know it - use it.

Comment: That's a No-break Space.  You'll want to use that so that part of the number isn't formatted onto another line.